# Что будет, если я не пропишу значение value?

Tags: html

У меня такой вопрос. Value задает значение элементу.Но что будет, если я не напишу value? Значением по умолчанию будет вариант ответа, который прописан в option/checkbox/radio?
Например:

```html
<form action="#">
  <label for="1">Milk</label><input id="1" name="information" type="checkbox"> <br>
  <label for="2">Water</label><input id="2" name="information" type="checkbox"> <br>
  <label for="3">Tea</label><input id="3" name="information" type="checkbox"> 
</form>
```

То есть если мы отметим первый вариант, то значением первого варианта будет milk? Как это работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function checkValues() {
  console.log($("form").serialize());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <label for="1">Milk</label><input id="1" name="information" type="checkbox"> <br>
  <label for="2">Water</label><input id="2" name="information" type="checkbox"> <br>
  <label for="3">Tea</label><input id="3" name="information" type="checkbox"> 
</form>
<button onclick="checkValues()">Click</button>
```